# geolocalization of tweets

Tags: api, social-media, geocoding, programming

Do you know a technique to find spatial indicators using the package TwitteR in R?
For instance if I have to find the word "dog" using the package twitteR, but I miss the coordinates, there is the possibility to find the localization of the tweets thanks to some indications included in the  time-zone, websites, UTC24offset,text message. How can I say to R to detect my list of Tweets contains the word "dog" using the spatial indicators just mentioned?

Comment: There was a recent post on twitter's blog that the USGS is using twitter to verify earthquakes : https://blog.twitter.com/2015/usgs-twitter-data-earthquake-detection  ... you might try checking if the people/projects mentioned have any presentations, or try contacting them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the **utc_offset** or **time_zone** keys of the *user* section of a tweet.json (I trimmed the `user` dict) - [full tweet description](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets):

```
"user":{  
   "utc_offset":-28800,
   "time_zone":"Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
   "created_at":"Wed May 23 06:01:13 +0000 2007"
       }
```

But this is based on the user account and not on a specific tweet. Still, it gives you a probabilistic geolocation for non-geotagged tweets.